# Is there a way to identify whether dataloss is present while consuming data from Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

Wanted to know is there any way to identify the dataloss from the consumer while consuming data from the Kafka Topic.
Producer has sent message to the Topic but consumer is not received.
For example few messages published at 6:38:00 and few were published at 6:38:02 and few were published at 6:38:03.
messages published at 6:38:02 will be missed while consuming and writing to delta location.

I am using below condition while consuming the data
"spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true"
"spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "100"